# An equality regarding Dirac operator

Tags: geometric-analysis, dirac-operator

Let S be a spinor bundle on a closed Riemannian manifold M, with a spin connection A. Then for a spinor field $\phi$, we know
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\Delta|\phi|^2=\langle \nabla_A^*\nabla_A \phi,\phi\rangle-|\nabla_A \phi|^2
\end{align*}

I am looking for a similar expression for the term
\begin{align*}
\langle D_A^2\phi,\phi\rangle-|D_A \phi|^2
\end{align*}

where $D_A$ is the Dirac operator w.r.t. the connection $A$.